bot detection, hasInconsistentGPUFeatures
I am trying to set up a playwright bot that can bypass bot detection and I am using https://deviceandbrowserinfo.com/are_you_a_bot to test. I am failing "isWebGLInconsistent" (though my main browser is as well), "isAutomatedWithCDP", which it seems false positive's with opening devtools, though it is true even without devtools open, and "hasInconsistentGPUFeatures".
I have no idea what this last one is, or how to get around it.
the first one seems to be fixed with flag --use-gl, the second one seems a bit hard to fix since there i think are many different effects CDP has on your browser and the last one is hard to search up at all. chatgpt didnt understand the question really either.

I have the same problem. Did you manage to find something related to this problem?

I use nodriver now, its the new undetected_chromedriver
